# SQL Server - check whether record with specific value exists

Tags: sql-server

I have quite simple problem in SQL Server:

User can have 12 items that are represented in table with ID and Slot (slot is 0-11). When an item is picked up, it should be placed into the lowest empty slot.

I am using following script but it returns first empty slot after the first used slot:

```
SELECT coalesce ((SELECT MIN(Slot) + 1 FROM Items N1 WHERE N1.name = 'abc'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Items N2 WHERE N2.name = 'abc'
AND N2.Slot = N1.Slot + 1) AND Slot<11),0)
```

I would need the script to find lowest slot that does not exist yet. Hope it makes sense :)

An example - if the table contains following records, it does not work, returns 5 (should return 0):

```
ID  Slot Name
10    3  abc
11    4  abc
```

With this data, it does return 2 correctly.

```
ID  Slot Name
10    0  abc
11    1  abc
```

The script should return 1 as this is the first not used number (Slot) lower than 11.

Comment: Can you post some seed data and what you would expect the next value to be given that data so we can be clear what you need.

Comment: Paul: and that is strange. If you have 3 and 4, you would expect 0 as well. But I get 5 instead.

Comment: Does my Edited Answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT coalesce (
                    (SELECT MIN(N1.Slot) + 1 
                       FROM Items N1
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN Items N2 ON N1.Slot+1 = N2.Slot
                      WHERE N1.name = 'abc'
                        AND N2.Slot IS NULL
                        AND N1.Slot < 11)
                   ,0)
```

Comment: Thanks, however that does not work either. It still returns the first empty slot after existing one. I add the data to original post

Comment: true. according to your edited question with example, the above wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Slot INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (10, 0, 'ABC')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (11, 2, 'ABC')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (12, 3, 'ABC')

INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (13, 0, 'EFG')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (14, 1, 'EFG')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (15, 2, 'EFG')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (16, 3, 'EFG')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (17, 4, 'EFG')

SELECT
    i.Name,
    MIN(i.Slot + 1) AS LowestSlot
FROM
    @Items i 
    LEFT JOIN @Items i2 ON i2.Slot = i.Slot + 1 AND i2.Name = i.Name
WHERE
    -- i.Slot + 1 < 11 or, i.Slot < 10
    i.Slot < 10 AND
    i2.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY
    i.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

The major difficulty with the problem is that it needs to *invent* data. How does MSSQL know that your slots are numbered 0 - 11? Why not -3 - 19? Obviously, the answer is "because you said so", but you need to tell MSSQL.

In MSSQL you can create a table variable to hold the basic slot information, and then join your Items table against it to figure out which ones are empty

```
DECLARE @tv TABLE (
    ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @tv
VALUES
(0),
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10),
(11)

SELECT
    MIN(t.ID) + 1 AS EmptySlot
FROM
    @tv t
    LEFT JOIN Item i
        ON t.ID = i.ID
WHERE
    ISNULL(i.Slot, 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @simon's query. It works in SQL-Server 2008:

```
SELECT
    MIN(t.Slot) AS EmptySlot
FROM
      ( VALUES
        (0), (1), (2), (3),
        (4), (5), (6), (7),
        (8), (9), (10), (11) 
      ) AS t(Slot)
    LEFT JOIN
        Items AS i
      ON i.Slot = t.Slot
WHERE
    i.Slot IS NULL
```

or:

```
SELECT
    MIN(t.Slot) AS EmptySlot
FROM
  ( VALUES
    (0), (1), (2), (3),
    (4), (5), (6), (7),
    (8), (9), (10), (11) 
  ) AS t(Slot)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Items AS i
        WHERE i.Slot = t.Slot
      )
```